# The following _TypeError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#f907f): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

main.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:icardi/pages/choose_location.dart';
    import 'package:icardi/pages/home.dart';
    import 'package:icardi/pages/loading.dart';
    void main() =>runApp(MyApp());
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => Loading(),
            '/home': (context) => Home(),
            '/location': (context) => ChooseLocation()
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

home.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class Home extends StatefulWidget {
      const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
    }
    
    class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
      Map data = {};
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        data = data.isEmpty ? data :ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
        print(data);
        String bgImage = data['dayTime'] ? 'day.jpg' : 'night.jpg';
        return Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            decoration:  BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('assets/$bgImage') ,fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 40, 40, 0),
              child: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  FlatButton.icon(
                    onPressed: ()  async {
                       dynamic result= await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                       setState(() {
                         data = {
                           'time': result['time'],
                           'location': result['location'],
                           'dayTime': result['dayTime'],
                           'flag': result['flag'],
                         };
                       });
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                        Icons.edit_location,
                    color: Colors.grey[300],),
                    label: Text('edit location',
                    style: TextStyle( color: Colors.grey[300]),),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Row(
                   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        data['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 28,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 40),
                  Text(
                    data ['time'], style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 66, color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

loading.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:icardi/services/world_time.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
    
    class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
      const Loading({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
     @override
      State<Loading> createState() => _LoadingState();
    
    }
    
    class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
    
      setupWorldTime() async {
      WordTime instance = WordTime(flag: 'uganda.png', location: 'Kampala', url: 'Africa/Kampala');
      await instance.getTime();
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/home', arguments: {
        'location': instance.location, 'flag': instance.flag, 'time': instance.time,
        'dayTime': instance.dayTime
      });
      setState(() {
        var time = instance.time;
      });
    }
    
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        setupWorldTime();
    
      }
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
          body: Center(
            child: SpinKitFadingCircle(
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 50,
    
            ),
          ),
    
          );
    
    
      }
    }
```

worldtime.dart:

```
    import 'package:http/http.dart'as http;
    import 'package:http/http.dart';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
    class WordTime{
       String location;
      late String time;
       String flag;
       String url;
      late bool dayTime;
      WordTime({ required this.flag , required this.location, required this.url});
    Future<void> getTime  () async{
      try {
        Response  response= await http.get(Uri.parse('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/$url'));
        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print (data);
        String datetime = data['datetime'];
        String offset = data['utc_offset'].substring(1,3);
        DateTime now = DateTime.parse(datetime);
        now= now.add(Duration(hours: int.parse(offset)));
        time = DateFormat.jm().format(now);
        dayTime = now.hour >6 && now.hour <20 ? true : false;
      }
      catch (e){
        print(' the error is $e');
        time ='could not get time data';
      }
    
    
    }
    }
```

choose_location.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:icardi/services/world_time.dart';
    class ChooseLocation extends StatefulWidget {
    
    
      @override
      State<ChooseLocation> createState() => _ChooseLocationState();
    }
    
    class _ChooseLocationState extends State<ChooseLocation> {
      List<WordTime> locations =[
        WordTime(url:'Europe/London', location: 'London', flag: 'uk.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Europe/Berlin', location: 'Berlin', flag: 'germany.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Africa/Cairo', location: 'Cairo', flag: 'egypt.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Africa/Nairobi', location: 'Nairobi', flag: 'kenya.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Africa/Kampala', location: 'Kampala', flag: 'ug.png'),
        WordTime(url:'America/Chicago', location: 'Chicago', flag: 'usa.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Asia/Jakarta', location: 'Jakarta', flag: 'indoo.png'),
        WordTime(url:'Asia/Seoul', location: 'Seoul', flag: 'korea.jpg'),
        WordTime(url:'Europe/Athens', location: 'Athens', flag: 'greece.png'),
    
      ];
      void updateTime(int index) async{
        WordTime instance = locations[index];
        await instance.getTime();
        // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
        Navigator.pop(context, {'location': instance.location, 'flag': instance.flag, 'time': instance.time,
        'dayTime': instance.dayTime});
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Locations'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
            elevation: 0,
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: locations.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,  index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1, horizontal: 6),
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    onTap: (){
                     updateTime(index);
                    },
                    title: Text(locations[index].location),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/${locations[index].flag}'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

the error i get is:
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device TECNO K7...
Restarted application in 4,790ms.
D/libc-netbsd( 7099): getaddrinfo: worldtimeapi.org get result from proxy gai_error = 0
I/flutter ( 7099): {abbreviation: EAT, client_ip: 197.239.7.195, datetime: 2022-09-14T12:27:41.758821+03:00, day_of_week: 3, day_of_year: 257, dst: false, dst_from: null, dst_offset: 0, dst_until: null, raw_offset: 10800, timezone: Africa/Kampala, unixtime: 1663147661, utc_datetime: 2022-09-14T09:27:41.758821+00:00, utc_offset: +03:00, week_number: 37}
I/flutter ( 7099): {}

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building Home(dirty, state: _HomeState#f907f):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is at:

```
String bgImage = data['dayTime'] ? 'day.jpg' : 'night.jpg';
```

`data['dayTime']` is null, because you assign it to an empty value at line

```
data = data.isEmpty ? data : ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map;
```

I believe you want to assign it as

```
data = data.isEmpty ? ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as Map : data;
```